# XSL - Check nodes at the same level

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this structure in XML:

```
<report>
  <text>
    <chapter>1</chapter>
    <chapter>2
        <section>2.1</section>
    </chapter>
    <chapter>3</chapter>
  </text>
</report>
```

In my DTD, I have:

```
 <!ELEMENT text (#PCDATA | chapter |section)*>
```

Because of this, in my XSL, i want the garantee that I don't have a `chapter` and a `section` in the same level, before doing the transformation. So, i can't have this

```
<report>
  <text>
    <chapter>1</chapter>
    <chapter>2
        <section>2.1</section>
    </chapter>
    <section>3</section>
  </text>
</report>
```

My XSL

```
<xsl:template match="chapter">

    <div class="chapter">   
        <h2> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="chapter-title"/>
        </h2>       
        <hr/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="text() | section "/>
    </div>
</xsl:template> 
<xsl:template match="section">
    <div class="section">
        <h3>  
            <xsl:apply-templates select="section-title"/>
        </h3>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

How can I check if a section and a chapter are at the same level, in XSL? 
Thanks.

Comment: You want to validate or you want xml to transform into expected xml format?

Comment: I want to validate. I just transform a section if it is not at the same level of a chapter. @MindPeace i just edited my post with my current XSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following XSLT produces `true` as its output if `chapter` and `section` are at the same level, else nothing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="chapter and section">true</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the XPath axes, parent should work in this case:

```
<xsl:if test="count(parent::*/*) &gt; 0">...</xsl:if>
```

Select the parent node: `parent::*`

Select all elements nodes inside the parent node: `parent::*/*`

Count them and check here are more then zero: `count(parent::*/*) > 0`

`*` will return any element node, but not text node. You can use the element node name to select specific element nodes.

Comment: But, with that, how do i know that there is no chapter at the same level of a section? The thing is if i have a chapter at the same level of section, i cannot transform the section.

Answer (score 0):

You need `xsl:message`:

```
<xsl:template match="*[chapter][section]">
    <xsl:message terminate="yes">There are a section and a chapter on the same level</xsl:message>
</xsl:template>
```

terminate="yes" skips the process, if the processor comes to this message. If you just need a warning, switch to "no".

Maybe [Schematron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schematron) is interessting for you. In this case you would need:

```
<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" queryBinding="xslt2">
    <pattern>
        <rule context="*[chapter]">
            <report test="section">There are a section and a chapter on the same level</report>
        </rule>
    </pattern>
</schema>
```